# How to only enable button when two text fields are not empty - Swift + storyboard

Tags: swift, uikit

Recently, I am writing my own project with swift.
I use storyboard and create two text fields and one button.
How do I enable the button only when two text fields are not empty?

Here is what I had so far

```
@IBAction func enableNextBtn(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if !sender.text!.isEmpty {
       nextBtn.isEnabled = true
    } else {
       nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: You could connect the two UITextFields to your ViewController. Then you could write a func that checks wether both of the textFields are empty and disables / enables your button. Then you could call this function every time the content of one of your UITextFields changes. Does this help you or do you need help with implementing?

Comment: Hi ! You should probably look at your two text fields. When somthing change, you can ask the app if both of text fields are filled, and if so, enable the button. It looks like you're trying to do something similar to JavaScript (React / Vue) way of doing it with `v-if` attributes, iOS works differently :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. The way I connect the IBAfunction is ctrl+ drag to the view controller. I don't know how to wrap two IBAfunction into one function. I think some eample will be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 You need one IBOutlet for each TextField:

```
@IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
```

2 Don´t forget to conform to   UITextFieldDelegate like in:

```
MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{}
```

3 In viewDidLoad set self as UITextFieldDelegate for your TextFields:

```
textField1.delegate = self
textField2.delegate = self
```

4 implemente the following method which is called with every keystroke:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    nextBtn.isEnabled = !textField1.text?.isEmpty && !textField2.text?.isEmpty
return true
}
```

Hope this approach helps.

Comment: Hi, when I test your code in 4, an error pops up and says the value of optional type 'Bool?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Bool', do you know what does it mean?

Comment: After I set the textfield.text? to textfield.text! the error was gone. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Hi, sorry to answering to late but maybe it helps to clarify. What happens is that the expression with error is evaluating to an Bool? that is an "optional Bool" which is not equal to a "Bool" in order to get a Bool from a Bool? you need to unwrap it... you just did it with textfield.text!